# Pointer error when trying to use "strcpy" in C to copy char elements from one array to another

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is check if the word entered by the user has first five alphabetical letters and if it has, I need to copy those letters to another array.But it gives me an error saying "passing argument 1 of strcpy makes pointer from integer without cast[enabled by default]".

```
char s1[100];
char a1[100];
char alpha[5]={'a','b','c','d','e'};
int i,j,k=0;

printf("Enter a word");
fgets(s1,100,stdin);

for(i=0;i<strlen(s1);i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<5;j++)
   {
     if(s1[i]==alpha[j])
     {
       strcpy(a1[k],s1[i]);
       k++;
     }
   }
}
```

Need help to figure out what is wrong with this

Comment: You are passing `strcpy` 2 `char`s. It takes 2 `char*`s

Comment: `a1[k] = s1[i];` instead of `strcpy(a1[k],s1[i]);` ?

Comment: program looks fine but unable to figure out the error. Can you give mire detail about the error?

Comment: The error is-: "passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default] . "expected 'char *' but the argument is of type 'char'. "

Comment: Won't strcpy() copy the whole char * to an other char *? (Plus the fact you can't pass two `char` to `strcpy()`) So you won't be able to select the letters you copy.
Use `a1[k] = s1[i];` , as suggested.

Comment: I tried a1[k]= s1[i]  but it displays some vague characters for a1 ex-: if s1 is "abc" , a1 displays as "abc!"

Comment: @Zac C string needs null-terminated. `a1[k] = '\0';` after outer for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one loop:
Replace char by char:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
{
    a1[i] = s1[i];
}
```

Or, use strcpy like this: `strcpy(a1, s1);`

---

Answering your comment:

> I tried a1[k]= s1[i] but it displays some vague characters for a1 ex-: if s1 is "abc" , a1 displays as "abc!"

C strings need to be null terminated.
Try doing this:

```
char s1[100] = {0};
char a1[100] = {0};
```

Small example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[100] = {0};
    char a1[100] = {0};
    int i,j,k=0;

    printf("Enter a word: ");
    fgets(s1,100,stdin);

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++)
    {
        a1[i] = s1[i];
    }

    printf("a1 now contains: %s", a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`strcpy` has two input parameters `char *`. You can't use it for two characters. If you want to copy one character from one array to another then you need to use `= operator` as `a1[k] = s1[i]`